# Safari issue - flash image expands from container

Tags: css, safari, flash, margin

I have flash element on my site which act strange on Safari browser only, it expand from the container and breaks everything around. I don't know what's happening, http://itmjobs.ro/lidl/eu.html
Anyone experience this and knows the solution ?

Comment: Try running your page through this validator - lots of errors: http://validator.w3.org - including having an iframe within the HEAD of your page - should only be within the BODY.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-website-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it